# bad control character error in json parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

When parsing a JSON object I am getting "bad control character" error in the Firebug console. There are lot of questions and solutions in this site; but I am unable to crack this issue. I believe I am doing something silly. Please point me to my mistake.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Purus/Eqz2r/

If we change the json data to a plain text instead of html tags, it works.

*Error:*

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal
someVal = JSON.parse(sign);
```

**NOTE:**

- The JSON data is obtained from a PHP function using json_encode
  function.
- The json output looks valid in jsonlint

*Below is the code I have used.*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var sign = '{"data":"<br\/><br\/>----------<br \/>\r\nFrom Yahoo Team<br \/>\r\n<a href=\"http:\/\/localhost\/base\/1-yahoo-logo.jpg\" target=\"_blank\"><img style=\"padding: 5px;\" src=\"http:\/\/localhost\/plugins\/1-yahoo-logo.jpg\" height=\"120\" width=\"196\" \/><\/a>"}';

   someVal = JSON.parse(sign);
   $(".demo").append(someVal.data);
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to escape your escapes :)

Use double `\\` instead of `\`

http://jsfiddle.net/Eqz2r/2/

Comment: Thanks. But how can I do that in PHP before passing on the JSON in JS.

Comment: actually, replace on server side or js side I guess it doesn't matter?

Comment: Thats great news. I could not understand what to replace with what. In your fiddle, I see sign.replace("\n", "\n") which I could not make sense replacing same char by itself.

Comment: When I try sign.replace("\", "\\") it says illegal character. I am pretty new to JS. Please bear with me.

Comment: that was carried over from your fiddle ;). Try doing it on the php side, i'm not familiar with php but you need to swap single slashes for double (try this i found: `str_replace("\\", "\\\\", $data);`)

Comment: Great. It works now. Thanks for your help. Accepting your answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
var s= JsonString;
$.parseJSON(s.replace(/\s+/g,""));
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the \r and \n.  These need to be escaped as

```
\\r
```

and

```
\\n
```

in the JSON string